# Web2py Modules: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html.parser. Do you need to install a parser library?

Tags: web2py, web2py-modules

This question is specific to Web2py Framework. The code is working fine outside it.

I have installed bs4 and BeautifulSoup4 in the Modules directory.

```
sudo pip install bs4 --target /home/www-data/web2py/applications/myapp/modules
sudo pip install beautifulsoup4 --target /home/www-data/web2py/applications/myapp/modules
```

But Still then I am getting Error:

Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html.parser. Do you need to install a parser library?

I upgraded bs4

```
sudo pip install --upgrade bs4 --target /home/www-data/web2py/applications/rip/modules
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

But its the same error again.

I am on:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

Web2py:

Version
2.15.4-stable+timestamp.2017.09.02.04.02.22
(Running on Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu), Python 2.7.12)
```

Comment: Which operating system and version of web2py? Have you tried installing lxml?

Comment: $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial

Web2py:

Version
2.15.4-stable+timestamp.2017.09.02.04.02.22
(Running on Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu), Python 2.7.12)

Comment: I have not tried lxml as the code is working fine outside the web2py framework in the same system.